# What unexpected process happened in this test()?why Always overwrite ch[0 1 2...]?

Tags: c++

I want to input some `char[100]`, then store them in `char *ch[100]`, but failed.

`ch[0,1,...last]` would be normal in `test()`.

But `ch[0...last]==ch[last]` when exit from `test()`.

What happened?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

char *ch[100];
int N=0;

int test(char *strValue)
{
    ch[N++]=strValue;//normal in test() when debug 
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[100];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>str;
        test(str);
    }
    cout<<"N:"<<N<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<<ch[i]<<endl;//abnomal!!! ch[0...N-1] become ch[N-1],what happened?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: *"How many `str` do I  have in `main()`?"* and *"If I pass the same `str` to `test()` each time and assign the address of `strValue` to `ch` -- why would I expect `ch` to point to something different?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
ch[N++]=strValue;
```

copies the *pointer* not the string.

That means all elements of `ch` will point to the very same string, which will only have the contents of the last input.

The natural C++ solution is to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects, and [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) new strings as needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int test(std::vector<std::string>& ch, std::string const& str)
{
    ch.push_back(str);
}

int main()
{
    // Container for all our strings
    std::vector<std::string> strings;

    // The number of strings to read
    size_t number_of_strings;
    std::cin >> number_of_strings;

    // Create space for the strings (slight optimization)
    strings.reserve(number_of_strings);

    // Read the strings
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_strings; ++i)
    {
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        test(strings, str);  // Will add the string to the vector
    }

    // Print the number of strings we've read
    std::cout << "N:" << strings.size() << '\n';

    // Lastly display all strings
    for (auto const& str : strings)
    {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }
}
```